# DirectX11 pixel shader in pipeline is missing

Tags: c++, directx11, fragment-shader, rasterization

I'm writing a program which displays a MS3D model using DirectX, and unfortunately, the result shows nothing on the screen. 
When I use the Graphics Debugger from Visual Studio 13, I notice that the pixel shader is missing from the pipeline, as it is shown in the below picture

[image]

This is my pixel shader source code:

```
 cbuffer SkinningTransforms
 {
    matrix WorldMatrix; 
    matrix ViewProjMatrix;
 };
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Inter-stage structures
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
struct VS_INPUT
{
    float3  position        : POSITION;
    int4    bone            : BONEID;
    float4  weights         : BONEWEIGHT;
    float3  normal          : NORMAL;
    float3  tangent         : TANGENT;
    float2  tex             : TEXCOORD;
};
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
struct VS_OUTPUT
{
    float4 position         : SV_Position;
    float3 normal           : NORMAL;
    float3 light            : LIGHT;
    float2 tex              : TEXCOORDS;
};

Texture2D       ColorTexture : register( t0 );           
SamplerState    LinearSampler : register( s0 );

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
VS_OUTPUT VSMAIN( in VS_INPUT input )
{
    VS_OUTPUT output;
    //Transform vertex and pass them to the pixel shader
    return output;
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
float4 PSMAIN( in VS_OUTPUT input ) : SV_Target
{
    // Calculate the lighting
    float3 n = normalize( input.normal );
    float3 l = normalize( input.light );


    float4 texColor = ColorTexture.Sample( LinearSampler, input.tex );

    float4 color = texColor * (max(dot(n,l),0) + 0.05f );
    return( color );
}
```

As I was known from Graphics Debugger, all of the graphics event are right. I listed in below important events, which might be relating to Pixel Shader:

```
106:(obj:4) ID3D11Device::CreateDepthStencilView(obj:24,NULL,obj:25)*
108:(obj:5) ID3D11DeviceContext::OMSetRenderTargets(8,{obj:1,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL},obj:25)*
109:(obj:5) ID3D11DeviceContext::ClearRenderTargetView(obj:1,addr:21)*
111:(obj:5) ID3D11DeviceContext::ClearDepthStencilView(obj:25,1,1.000f,0)*
119:(obj:4) ID3D11Device::CreateSamplerState(addr:24,obj:27)*
134:(obj:4) ID3D11Device::CreatePixelShader(addr:27,21056,NULL,obj:30)*
135:CreateObject(D3D11 Pixel Shader,obj:30)
136:(obj:5) ID3D11DeviceContext::PSSetShader(obj:30,NULL,0)*
137:(obj:5) ID3D11DeviceContext::PSSetSamplers(0,1,{obj:27})*
139:(obj:4) ID3D11Device::CreateTexture2D(addr:28,addr:5,obj:31)*
140:CreateObject(D3D11 Texture2D,obj:31)
142:(obj:4) ID3D11Device::CreateShaderResourceView(obj:31,NULL,obj:32)*
143:CreateObject(D3D11 Shader Resource View,obj:32)
144:(obj:5) ID3D11DeviceContext::PSSetShaderResources(0,1,{obj:32})*
146:(obj:4) ID3D11Device::CreateRasterizerState(addr:29,obj:33)*
147:CreateObject(D3D11 Rasterizer State,obj:33)
152:(obj:5) ID3D11DeviceContext::RSSetState(obj:33)*
154:(obj:5) ID3D11DeviceContext::RSSetViewports(1,addr:30)*
156:(obj:4) ID3D11Device::CreateBlendState(addr:11,obj:34)*
157:CreateObject(D3D11 Blend State,obj:34)
159:(obj:5) ID3D11DeviceContext::OMSetBlendState(obj:34,addr:31,-1)*
162:(obj:4) ID3D11Device::CreateDepthStencilState(addr:32,obj:35)*
163:CreateObject(D3D11 Depth-Stencil State,obj:35)
165:(obj:5) ID3D11DeviceContext::OMSetDepthStencilState(obj:35,0)*
```

I debugged all of the function in the above list, and all of them return OK. Nothing wrong.
My question is what is the reason the pixex shader is missing from pipleline, which in turn may result in the empty screen.

Comment: Have you tried D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG?

Comment: Yeah, I added it, but it throw nothing. I check the Device Context and the pixel shader is set correctly.

Comment: Doesn't VSPix helpfully hide the PS step if all the fragments are rejected?

Answer (score 1):

I just spotted something, which doesn't look right. The alpha value returned from your pixel shader could easily end up as zero, which will make everything transparent. Try forcing it to be 1.0 like this:

```
float4 color = texColor * (max(dot(n,l),0) + 0.05f );

// At this point color.a could be zero which will make things transparent
color.a = 1.0; // Could also use texColor.a

return( color );
```

Of course the colour will most likely be black after the fix if that was what's wrong, so make sure the background color isn't black.